# Bash/WSL terminals blank/frozen - Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been developing Web applications on my Windows 10 PC, using VSCode with the Ubuntu/WSL terminal for the past month. Everything has been working fine so far.

Today I started up my PC and the Ubuntu App on Windows shows a blank terminal, as does Bash.exe and WSL.exe. I cannot type or do anything in the terminals.

Powershell, CMD and Git Bash are working fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed by going to "Turn windows features on or off" in Settings, disabled Linux Subsystem, restarted PC, and then enabled and restarted PC.